# How to bind a List of Dictionaries to a Xamarin.Forms Picker?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, xamarin.forms, picker

I'm trying to bind a list of dictionaries to a Picker's ItemsSource using MVVM pattern. But the items don't get bound.

This is the property in my Model:

```
public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Options { get; set; }
```

This is how the Json comes from API:

```
"options": [
              {
                "key": "06/30/2021",
                "value": "06/30/2021"
               },
               {
                 "key": "05/31/2021",
                 "value": "05/31/2021"
                },
                {
                  "key": "04/30/2021",
                  "value": "04/30/2021"
                }
           ]
```

This is my XAML:

```
<controls:BorderlessPicker Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Title="{Binding DisplayName}" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedContent.Attributes.Options}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}" >
                                                        
</controls:BorderlessPicker>
```

Comment: why isn't this just a `Dictionary<string,string>`?

Comment: It doesn't deserialize when it is just a `Dictionary<string,string>`

Comment: Then modify the data after you deserialize it

Answer (score 0):

As Jason commented, you can directly use the Dictionary instead of a list of dictionary.

You can give this a try -

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> _options { get; set; }

_options = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {

              {
                "06/30/2021",
                "06/30/2021"
               },
               {
                 "05/31/2021",
                 "05/31/2021"
                },
                {
                  "04/30/2021",
                  "04/30/2021"
                }
        };

    public List<string> Options { get; } = _options.Keys.ToList();

    private KeyValuePair<string, string> _selectedItem;
    public KeyValuePair<string, string> SelectedItem
    {
      get => _selectedItem;
      set => _selectedItem = value;
    }
```

```
<controls:BorderlessPicker Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
   Title="{Binding DisplayName}" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedContent.Attributes.Options}" 
   ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}"
   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" >
                                                        
</controls:BorderlessPicker>
```

You can get the key of the selected Item like `SelectedItem.Key`

Answer (score 0):

If you use data binding for Picker, you could refer to [Populating a Picker with data using data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource#populating-a-picker-with-data-using-data-binding).

According to official documentation, firs we could define a **List** of **PickerItem** which Picker ItemSource binds to.

```
public List<PickerItem> Options { get; set; } = new List<PickerItem>();
```

And for **PickerItem**, we could define it like this:

```
public class PickerItem
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then we should change the json data to our **Options** list. We could use Newtonsoft.json nuget.

```
Options = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PickerItem>>(json_data);
```

Finally, our custom control could consume the Option list:

```
<controls:BorderlessPicker ...    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedContent.Attributes.Options}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}" />
```

Hope it works for you.